# controlling power by AC frequency

Tags: arduino, noise, frequency, phase

I am working on circuit that will control a heat pad using a triac and microcontroller.
In order to reach minimal EMI noise rather than phase controll I am controlling the frequency.

schema:

[image]
As I said, mine primary concern is noise as I want this device to pass EMC tests. Only measurement I can do by myself now that can indirectly point to noise issues is FFT.
Upfront I'll say, my load is heating pad 220V, 200W and I'm using that one for all my measurements.

I did 3 types of measurements:

a) opto-coupler for finding zero-crossings connected to 24V transformer with load connected also to this transformer's secondary:
[image]

b) opto-coupler still connected to transformer, but load on the mains phase:
[image]

c) opto-coupler connected directly to mains with R1 being 33K 2W (yes, gets hot quickly):
[image]

Here comes my first question:
am I interpreting this measurement right, saying I have ±50dB noise on first 200Hz range? What does it mean? is it any significant? if so, how can I improve things?

---

Another observation I got is that during 'b)' measurement the phase I got out of transformer and used as zero-crossing reference was shifted from the direct phase from AC mains connect on the load. Mind you, I have added an additional triac-opening pulse length to show you the symmetrical wave as there is; to illustrate this effect I set the code to open triac for every half-cycle crossing (to mimic direct AC) which looks like this with the transformer on optocoupler:

[image]

So you see "broken periods" in there, but when I leave out transformer and connect AC mains directly (resistor) to the opto-triac it is better:

[image]

So, second question is: would you expect it? me not.. I mean everything takes time, but on this scale that much of distortion?!...I wanted to have an transformer to not need to have so rugged parts for zc. Measurements but seems like I will need to employ some 4-5W resistors. Or do I have other options on how to make it safe and "in-sync"?

Parts I'm using are the same as in schema.

Thank you for reactions

Comment: *I am controlling the frequency* <-- that needs some explanation.

Comment: I know when phase zero crosses, I have microcontroller so I can open triac when I want. on the shots you see I allowed every 5th half-cycle that results in 10hz

Comment: Sub-harmonic control is not allowed by most utility companies, if you intend to market and sell it. Please edit your question and start sentences with capital letter.

Comment: so, nobody here can interpret that FFT? that's hard to believe